# Not sure how to properly subclass UIApplication while using storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to return to my storyboard's initial viewcontroller after X time of user inactivity (no touch events fired). After some research I see that the most common way of detecting inactivity is to fire an NSTimer and reset the interval when an event is fired. To detect a fired event, we override  [UIApplication sentEvent:] in a subclass of UIApplication. This is the part where I'm kind of stuck.

I'm looking at this project as reference

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/

https://github.com/elc/ELCUIApplication

I'm not sure how to implement a similar functionality when working with storyboards. I tried something similar to that github projet; I created a new class that was a subclass of UIApplication, overrode the needed method and finally changed the targeted class in the main function (from my appdelegate to the new class that subclassed UIApplication). By doing so I got the following error

*The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.*

The appDelegate in the github is a subclass of NSObject and manually loads up the initial view in his window property from what I understand, while my appDelegate is a subclass of UIResponder which itself is a superclass of UIApplication. I'm not sure how to proceed, I already have the window property in my AppDelegate and synthesized, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you changed the wrong argument to `UIApplicationMain`.

The default call to `UIApplicationMain` looks like this:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

The third argument (`nil` by default) is the name of the `UIApplication` class to use.  If it's nil, the app just uses `UIApplication`.

The fourth argument is the name of the `UIApplicationDelegate` class to use.

It sounds like you changed the fourth argument, but you should have changed the third argument:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv,
    NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]),
    NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Comment: @rob +1 it works for xcode 4.5 as UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([ELCUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([YouSaidItAppDelegate class])); Thanks...