# UIApplication subclassing options

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiapplication

We all know that normally we don't have any UIApplication subclasses in iOS applications. I have noticed that UIApplication is subclassed for implementing timeout functionality in applications. In that purpose we can catch 'sentEvent:' method fired by the OS and perform our own logics to implement timeout functionality.

Is there any other uses with subclassing UIApplication ?

Comment: I don't see how to do it, the first class you can specify (as far as I can see) is your appDelegate (in the main.m file) By that stage the application object is already created.

You can easily catch all events at appDelegate or UIWindow level, where did you 'notice' this being done ? (because it sounds interesting)

Comment: @Jef See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201577/496969

Comment: Ah yep, thanks.  I've read this just recently in an earlier edition of Matt's book, Pushing the limits iOs5 i think.  Did you find any reason to do it? (any event that could not instead be handled in the delegate or in a UIWindow subclass?